# Why does a concatenation of integers and strings behave like this?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

This code:

```
public void main(String[] args)
{
    String s1 = 50+40+"Hello"+50+50;
    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Gives output of: `90Hello5050`

Why?

Comment: No guesses?  Not one?  Are you used to JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

It's just a matter of precedence and associativity. Your code is equivalent to:

```
String s1 = (((50 + 40) + "Hello") + 50) + 50;
```

So that's:

```
String s1 = ((90 + "Hello") + 50) + 50;
```

which is:

```
String s1 = ("90Hello" + 50) + 50;
```

which is:

```
String s1 = "90Hello50" + 50;
```

which is:

```
String s1 = "90Hello5050";
```

If you wanted `90Hello100` you should use brackets to make it explicit. I'd write it as:

```
String s1 = (50 + 40) + "Hello" + (50 + 50);
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the  [Java Language Specification, Section 15.7, "Evaluation Order"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7), operators in Java are evaluated **from left to right**.

That means that your concatenation is evaluated like it was written as

```
String s1 = (((50+40)+"Hello")+50)+50;
```

That's why it

- adds 50 and 40 to yield 90
- adds 90 and "Hello" to yield "90Hello"
- adds "90Hello" and 50 to yield "90Hello50"
- adds "90Hello50" and 50 to yield "90Hello5050"

In general, when you have a binary operation (like "+" in this case) that can be applied to a `String` and the computation involves a `String`, the other operand is converted into a `String` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java will concat your string from left to right. and it will add 50 and 40 with each other because they are `int` and then concat that to "hello" string and result is `str` because `int` and `str` will be `str` output. then "90hello" is `str` and it will contact with 50 which is `int` and the result as I said will be `str` and continue.